# Elisp function to search for end of sentence (full stop + space)

Tags: org-mode, search

I am devising a part of a function that searches for the next full stop (dot) and space as representing the end of a written sentence and inserts a new line.

So far I have come up with this:

```
(while (search-forward ". " nil t) (insert "\n\n"))
```

However, I believe that the `". "` (dot plus space) is not recognized as such. What is the right syntax for this?

Comment: Why do you think so? This works for me (after adding the missing closing paren).

Comment: You can also profit from built-in functions such as `org-forward-sentence`, which calls `forward-sentence` (which uses the configuration variable `sentence-end`).

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Comment: I can't modify the parameters of sentence-end because it would mess up my config. org-forward-sentence jumps to the end of a paragraph :(

Comment: Hey @NickD , you are right, it works!

Comment: However, I noticed I need to DEL the white space before inserting the new lines. This does not work:  while (search-forward ". " nil t) (org-delete-backward-char) (insert "\n\n")))

Comment: Try `(while (search-forward ". " nil t) (delete-backward-char 1) (insert "\n\n"))`. Read the doc string of `org-delete-backward-char`: it's for specialized use in tables.

Comment: Thank you! I had just checked what function DEL keybinding was binded to, and that came up. But it's true that it's specific for tables. I will add it to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

`sentence-end` is both a function and variable, if the variable is `nil`, the function returns the regular expression currently used for matching the end of a sentence. i suspect you don't need to change your config of it in this case though.

you can use it to avoid the problem mentioned by @gigiair, where a period followed by a space doesn't actually end a sentence (a sentence might also end with `.` + `"` + a space, or other things). using it in your snippet:

```
(while (search-forward-regexp (sentence-end))
  (delete-backward-char 1) (insert "\n\n"))
```

check the value of `sentence-end-base` to see how you are currently handling sentences that end with spaces.

Comment: Thanks so much. I checked and the value of my variable sentence-end-base is: "[.?!…‽][]\"'”’)}»›]*" I don't know what this means and how it differs from my own. I would expect this to find an end of sentence after U.S. in "...U.S. foreign policy is blahblahblah...". Right?

Comment: Actually, this is not working. It gives me: ""helm-M-x-execute-command: Search failed: "\\([.?!…‽][]\"'”’)}»›]*\\($\\|[  ]$\\| \\|[  ][  ]\\)\\|[。．？！]+\\)[   
]*"

Comment: The problem is that sentence-end considers all this a sentence: "This is U.S. foreign policy. This is U.S. foreign policy. This is U.S. foreign policy. This is U.S. foreign policy. This is U.S. foreign policy. This is U.S. foreign policy. This is U.S. foreign policy. This is U.S. foreign policy. This is U.S. foreign policy. " So it wouldn't parse it at all. For me a sentence would be "This is U.S. foreign policy".

Comment: from https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Sentences.html: If you want to use just one space between sentences, you can set the variable `sentence-end-double-space` to `nil` to make the sentence commands stop for single spaces. However, this has a drawback: there is no way to distinguish between periods that end sentences and those that indicate abbreviations. For convenient and reliable editing, we therefore recommend you follow the two-space convention. The variable `sentence-end-double-space` also affects filling (see Fill Commands).

Comment: I thought there was a list of abbreviations that use periods that could be skipped by `sentence-end` but i can't seem to find it.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @NickD:

`search-forward ". "` works just fine.
Then we would need to remove the white space before placing a new line like this:

```
(while (search-forward ". " nil t) (delete-backward-char 1) (insert "\n\n"))
```

Comment: This can detect false sentence endings. For example "Foo, foo, foo, etc. is a long phrase foo. Try it.".

Comment: I couldn't understand. Would you explain again? Thanks!

Comment: Not sure if the question is for me or not. The next point etc. is not an end of sentence period. Just an abbreviation sign.

Comment: Yes, that is a failure of my algorithm! It would detect as end of sentence something like: "this is U.S. foreign policy", and place an end of sentence after U.S. But I don't know how to improve this. You would need human knowledge for that.

Comment: The convention that Emacs generally follows is that the end of a sentence is a period followed by *two* spaces. If you follow that convention, then the confusion points are reduced (although not eliminated by any means). See [Sentences](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Sentences.html) in the Emacs manual.